# Installing modules for both Python 2 and 3

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I need to install some modules for Python: `python3-rospkg`, `python3-catkin-tools` and `python3-yaml`.

I need them to work for both `python2` and `python3`. But as soon as I `apt-get install` one of the above, the corresponding `python2` package is removed.

For example: I install `python3-rospkg`, `python-rospkg` gets removed and vice versa.

Why is that and how can I have both?

Comment: please refer  [here](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/python3.html) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268501/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-x-alongside-python-2-x)